# SIGTSTP signal handler to ignore/act on SIGTSTP based on condition

Tags: c, unix, signals

Like the question says, I want to handle the SIGTSTP signal differently based on certain conditions. My final code won't be this simple but I'm trying to get this to work first:

```c
static void stphandler(int signo) {

  sigset_t mask;

  //Unblock SIGTSTP

  sigemptyset( & mask);
  sigaddset( & mask, SIGTSTP);
  sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, & mask, NULL);

  if (getpid() != ultimateParent) {
    printf("Not the parent process\n");
    exit(0);
  } 

  else {
    printf("This is the parent process");
  }

}
```

Code on parent process initialization:

```c
ultimateParent=getpid();


sa_stp.sa_handler = stphandler;
sigemptyset(&sa_stp.sa_mask);
sa_stp.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
sigaction(SIGTSTP, &sa_stp, NULL);
```

Code to create child:

```c
//leave args blank. Keep wc waiting for an input
execErr=execvp("wc",args);

if(errno==EACCES)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: Permission Denied.\n",command);

}

else
{

    fprintf(stderr,"%s: Command not found.\n",command);
}

exit(0);
```

Here is what I did and the output I got:

**In the Parent:**

When the parent is running and I hit CTRL+Z the output is:
^Z

When I then hit the return key, the printf command executes on the next line:

"This is the parent process"

Question: Why does it wait for me to hit the return key to proceed?

**In the child**

It simply prints ^Z as many times as I generate the signal, goes to the next line with the return key- but ignores ctrl+D (which would generally cause wc to read EOF and finish execution) or any other signal for that matter, besides SIGQUIT.

Question: Why does it ignore further signals after ctrl+z? Is there any way to simply make the child exit instead?

I feel like I'm missing something significant about signals and signal handlers in general. Any help, articles or other references are appreciated.

Comment: It's not legal to call `printf` or `exit` from a signal handler. You can use `write` or `_exit` though.

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't really want to put the terminal in raw mode (see `termios(3)`)? IMO that's easier (just raise `SIGSTOP` from key press, rather than raising it from signal handler).

Comment: _exit(0) doesn't seem to be making any difference either. I'm not sure termios solves my problem.This is actually not what I want to do eventually. I'm just trying to get the conditional in the handler working so I can then do some other processing on it.